# Subtracting last 3 months data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I'm looking for how to subtract last 3 months.
This is what I figured so far, but this includes this month's data as it uses CURRENT_DATE().

```
SELECT
*
FROM
ga_123456
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 36 MONTH))
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Say today is August 20th, I am looking for the dates between May 1st to July 31st so that will be the previous 3 months.
Thank you.

Comment: Is table suffix in a date format?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Assuming your tables names are of that format `ga_YYYYMMDD

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM ga_*
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) 
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: To get data for current month, change MONTH to DAY in the second clause: `AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY))`

Answer (score 0):

If _TABLE_SUFFIX is in a date format:

```
SELECT * FROM ga_123456

WHERE DATEPART(month,_TABLE_SUFFIX) > DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, -3, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy,  _TABLE_SUFFIX) > DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(month, -3, getdate()))
```

Else, use CONVERT() function to adjust _TABLE_SUFFIX